# Problem with useNavigate() hook and onWheel event

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to switch routes with the onWheel event. If the deltaY property of the onWheel event > 0, I call the useNavigate hook to change the route. The problem is that when going back the route changes as many times as I turn the mouse wheel. How do I fix this bug?

```
const navigate = useNavigate()

const handleWheel = (e) => {
    e.deltaY > 0 && navigate("/newRoute")
}
```

Comment: Please read how to make a [mre]. I'm guessing your adding an event listener somewhere. Just remove it once it triggers?

Comment: Mouse wheel and scroll events are ***notoriously*** noisy. Try to remove the event listener when the condition is met, or set some "state" that it's been "handled" so only 1 navigation action is triggered.

Comment: You should be using turnary operator instead of using && inside a function

Comment: Actually, `addEventListener` has a built-in option to only run it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse wheel and scroll events are ***notoriously*** noisy. Try to remove the event listener when the condition is met, or set some "state" that it's been "handled" so only 1 navigation action is triggered.

Example:

```
const navigateRef = React.useRef();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleWheel = (e) => {
  if (e.deltaY > 0 && !navigateRef.current) {
    navigateRef.current = true;
    navigate("/newRoute");
  }
}
```